# Appending core data object into an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data

I want to append json object I save in core data into an array, but it's not working with append. how I can append core data object into an array.

this is my array

```
private var videos = [Video]()
```

this my function to fetch an api and store the json into core data

```
let params = ["part": "snippet", "q": "tausiyah \(name)", "key": "AIzaSyC2mn0PTL8JmSWEthvksdJLvsnwo5Tu9BA"]

        APIServices.shared.fetchData(url: APIServices.youtubeBaseURL, params: params, of: Item.self) { (items) in
            items.forEach({ (item) in
                print(item.id.videoId)
                let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
                privateContext.parent = CoreDataManager.shared.persistenceContainer.viewContext

                let video = Video(context: privateContext)
                video.title = item.snippet.title
                video.videoId = item.id.videoId

                do {
                    try privateContext.save()
                    try privateContext.parent?.save()
                    self.videos.append(video) // this is I can't append core data into my array
                } catch let saveErr {
                    print("Failed to save json data:", saveErr)
                }
            })
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
```

Comment: The fetch data will execute asynchronously. You need the `DispatchQueue.main.async` *inside* the fetch data closure.

Comment: @Paulw11 what do you mean? I need to add dispatch again so my append will work?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your }.  What do you mean by "not working" and "I can't append...".  What happens?  Do you get an error message?

Comment: @Paulw11 my array is empty but it is save in core data

Comment: What do you see if you print the array.count after the append?  It still looks like an asynchronous problem to me. Also show your `numberOfItems(in section:)` code

Comment: @Paulw11 inside the APIService there is a value to append, but outside the APIService the array is empty. This is my numberOfItem(in section:)

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return videos.count
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185414/discussion-between-paulw11-and-ferryawijayanto).

Answer (score 1):

try this and see the result:

```
private var videos = [Video]() {
   didSet {
      print("AAA: \(videos.last().title)")
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.collectionView.reloadData()
      }
   }
}
```

be sure that you have set numberOfItems & Section to you array.count